# Не всегда работает prop

Tags: jquery, javascript

Бывают случаи, когда prop не срабатывает. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Вот пример:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <label class="checkbox btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="tooltip" class="check-merge" checked="">
        </label>
        <label class="radio btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="mainModelMerge" checked="">
            Главная
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox btn">
            <input type="checkbox" class="select-on-check">
            Массовая
        </label>
</div>

(function($) {
    $('label.radio').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $('label.checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', true);    
})(jQuery);
```

В данном случае не работает `$('label.radio').prop('disabled', true);`, а attr работает.

Зависит ли это от браузера?

http://jsfiddle.net/e0r1jtz6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disabled не относится к свойствам label (их там всего 2), поэтому prop и не срабатывает.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже до этого дошел. И вообще, как понял, prop действует только на input. Разгребать такое в stackoverflow предлагают через css

Answer (score 1):

```
$('label.checkbox').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // блокируем
$('label.checkbox').removeAttr('disabled'); // разблокируем
```

Comment: Спасибо, также действует .attr('disabled', true) и .attr('disabled', false)